# Python: Appending an Object with a list to another object with a list; Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded

Tags: python, object, recursion, append

For my program, I have an object that has a value, and a list of objects that are of the same type.

```
class WordAndList:
Word = ""
List = []

def __init__(self, word):
    Word = word
```

After I create a few of them, I would like to append one onto the other.

```
newWL = WordAndList("Hello")
secondWL = WordAndList("my")
newWL.List.append(secondWL)
```

However, whenever I try to do anything to recursively access elements (such as print all words) from newWL, I get the Maximum Recursion Depth exceeded error.

Why does appending an object to a list (where that object also has a list) cause the list to repeat to infinity? What actually happens when an append occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run that code, I don't get that error -- it completes. That difference may be due to OS or similar (I'm on `Ubuntu`, `Python 2.7.6`), however, I don't think that code is doing what you intended.

The way it's written, the constructor isn't actually init'ing any object-level variables, just a local one. Thus, the object's **Word** and **List** members are empty-string and empty-list, respectively.

You would want something like this:

```
class WordAndList:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.Word = word
        self.List = []


newWL = WordAndList("Hello")
secondWL = WordAndList("my")
newWL.List.append(secondWL)
```

In terms of the `append`, it's adding another element to the end of the list with each call. So, when you call `append` in the code above with an instance of **WordAndList** as an argument, it's essentially appending a `reference` to that object to the list.

For example, if you `print` **newWL.List** in `pdb` after you append to it, it shows this:

```
[<__main__.WordAndList instance at 0x7f4162a50e18>]
```

Comment: This solved it, the key is the object-level variables in the constructor. I have bad Java influences while I'm programming in Python. I will definitely pay closer attention to this in the future.